# Redshift UPDATE prohibitively slow

Tags: sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have a table in a Redshift cluster with ~1 billion rows. I have a job that tries to update some column values based on some filter. Updating anything at all in this table is incredibly slow. Here's an example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE col1 = 'a value of col1'
  AND col2 = 12;
```

The above query returns in less than a second, because I have sortkeys on `col1` and `col2`. There is only one row that meets this criteria, so the result set is just one row. However, if I run:

```
UPDATE SOMETABLE
SET col3 = 20
WHERE col1 = 'a value of col1'
  AND col2 = 12;
```

This query takes an unknown amount of time (I stopped it after 20 minutes). Again, it should be updating one column value of one row.

I have also tried to follow the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-specify-a-column-list.html, which talks about creating a temporary staging table to update the main table, but got the same results.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: See if you have an open transaction on that row.  Try running SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity; and see if your update is waiting.

Comment: @Bob - just checked, doesn't look like anything is waiting.

Comment: You should provide your table and index definitions the version of postgres your on and any output of any commands you run.  Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: Also add an explain plan for your select and your update more information is a good thing for these types of things.

Comment: I don't know anything about redshift, i took a quick look at the documentation, it looks like it is postgres 8.x with deviations from postgres, like unsupported commands, etc. I don't know if you have tried this.  Maybe the update is moving the data from one node to another, and that is not working correctly.  so, can you insert the data in sometable, and then delete the old data? a billion rows is a lot of rows. dang.

Comment: Try collecting stats on the table by using command like 'analyze sometable(col1,col2,col3)' and also make sure the table is vacuumed for removing unnecessary deleted blocks and data is sorted in the table. If possible please share the explain plan of the query.

Answer (score 12):

You didn't mention what percentage of the table you're updating but it's important to note that an `UPDATE` in Redshift is a 2 step process:

1. Each row that will be changed must be first marked for deletion
2. Then a new version of the data must be written **for each column in the table**

If you have a large number of columns and/or are updating a large number of rows then this process can be very labor intensive for the database.

You could experiment with using a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement to create a new "updated" version of the table and then dropping the existing table and renaming the new table. This has the added benefit of leaving you with a fully sorted table.

Comment: Could you elaborate or reference an explanation on why "each column in the table" has to be rewritten when changing a single column? Also curious if UPDATE performance has been improved in the ~7 years since this answer was given. I seem to be able to do UPDATE's on our Redshift dataset with reasonable performance in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't think RedShift is designed for bulk updates, RedShift is designed for OLAP instead of OLTP, update operations are inefficient on RedShift by nature.

In this use case, I would suggest to do INSERT instead of UPDATE, while add another column of the TIMESTAMP, and when you do analysis on RedShift, you'll need extra logic to get the latest TIMESTAMP to eliminate possible duplicated data entries.

Comment: Redshift comments include the statement that inserts can be very slow.  This may not be a solution